# How to use google speech api with service account

Tags: api, google-cloud-storage, google-speech-api

Using the 'Using a service account' method from [this](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/auth) speech API document.

I'm doing this on my VM instance on GCP.

I can get my access token without this part `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=KEY_FILE` and skipping to this part `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token` seems to give me access-token.

But I keep getting the following error.

`{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}`

Then I tried using the OAuth2.0 Playground [here](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)

It works and gives me the 'request id' or request name, or the operation name. But then, when I try to get it with `https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/operations/YOUR_OPERATION_NAME?key=YOUR_API_KEY` I get an error

`{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
  }
}`

If you use bearer token, you can't use the API KEY to view your result?

What's they proper way to use the service account method for doing this?